# Горизонтальное выезжающее меню

Tags: html, css

Есть горизонтальное меню. Однако, мне надо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки подменю плавно выезжало, может тут нужны библиотеки JQuery, но в этом я плохо разбираюсь. И еще одна вещь: для показа меню требуется держать кнопку, как сделать так, чтобы оно сохранялось при нажатии, и уже при повторном нажатии скрывалось?

```css
ul {
  width: 30px;
  hidth: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

li ul {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: none;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #ffe;
  background-color: #5488af;
}

li:active ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a class="button" style="cursor: pointer width:20px; background-color:#0000FF">
      <font color="#FFFFFF">X</font>
    </a>
    <font color="#FFFFFF"><span style="background-color: #0000FF">
 </span></font>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="linkr1.html"><span style="background-color: #0000FF">
  <font color="#FFFFFF">Ссылка </font></span> </a>
        <font color="#FFFFFF">
          <span style="background-color: #0000FF"></li> 
  </span></font>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="linkr1.html"><span style="background-color: #0000FF">
  <font color="#FFFFFF">Ссылка</font></span></a>
            <font color="#FFFFFF"><span style="background-color: #0000FF"></li>
      </span></font>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="linkr1.html"><span style="background-color: #0000FF">
  <font color="#FFFFFF">Ссылка </font></span> </a>
                <font color="#FFFFFF">
                  <span style="background-color: #0000FF"></li>
     </span></font>
              </li>
            </ul>
            </body
```

Comment: гуглите `css transform` или  `jquery animate` - это самые простые способы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так, через `:focus`

```css
ul {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;

}

a ~ ul {
transition:300ms;
  transform: translate(-1000px,0);
  }

li ul {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: none;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #ffe;
  background-color: #5488af;
}

a:focus ~ ul {
  transform: translate(0,0);
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a class="button" tabindex="0" style="cursor: pointer width:20px; background-color:#0000FF">
      <font color="#FFFFFF">X</font>
    </a>
    <font color="#FFFFFF"><span style="background-color: #0000FF">
 </span></font>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="linkr1.html"><span style="background-color: #0000FF">
  <font color="#FFFFFF">Ссылка </font></span> </a>
        <font color="#FFFFFF">
          <span style="background-color: #0000FF"></li> 
  </span></font>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="linkr1.html"><span style="background-color: #0000FF">
  <font color="#FFFFFF">Ссылка</font></span></a>
            <font color="#FFFFFF"><span style="background-color: #0000FF"></li>
      </span></font>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="linkr1.html"><span style="background-color: #0000FF">
  <font color="#FFFFFF">Ссылка </font></span> </a>
                <font color="#FFFFFF">
                  <span style="background-color: #0000FF"></li>
     </span></font>
              </li>
            </ul>
            </body
```

---

если так не устраивает можно поменять `a` на `input type=checkbox`

```css
ul {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;

}

label[for="button"]{
  display:block;
  width:30px;
  color:white;
}

input ~ ul {
  transition:300ms;
  transform: translate(-1000px,0);
}

li ul {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: none;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #ffe;
  background-color: #5488af;
}

input:checked ~ ul {
  transform: translate(0,0);
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <label for="button" style="cursor: pointer width:20px; background-color:#0000FF">X</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="button" style="display:none"/>
    <font color="#FFFFFF"><span style="background-color: #0000FF">
 </span></font>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="linkr1.html"><span style="background-color: #0000FF">
  <font color="#FFFFFF">Ссылка </font></span> </a>
        <font color="#FFFFFF">
          <span style="background-color: #0000FF"></li> 
  </span></font>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="linkr1.html"><span style="background-color: #0000FF">
  <font color="#FFFFFF">Ссылка</font></span></a>
            <font color="#FFFFFF"><span style="background-color: #0000FF"></li>
      </span></font>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="linkr1.html"><span style="background-color: #0000FF">
  <font color="#FFFFFF">Ссылка </font></span> </a>
                <font color="#FFFFFF">
                  <span style="background-color: #0000FF"></li>
     </span></font>
              </li>
            </ul>
            </body
```

Comment: @НикитаБорискевич добавил второй сниппет